# JSONParse task error when filtering in chainlink Job Definition

Tags: chainlink

When writing a job definition that makes an HTTP GET request to an external API, which returns a json array of objects, is it possible to use a JSONPath expression in the job definition to filter the objects in the array based on the values of certain attributes in the objects?

For example in my job definition, I have following line meant to retrieve the "address" value in the object with a chain value equal to "BTC".

`parse_address [type="jsonparse" path="$[?(@.chain=='BTC')],address" data="$(fetch)"]`

This successfully retrieves the address value from the bellow array when I test the expression on jsonpath.com, but my chainlink job returns the following error:

```
parse_address jsonparse
JSONParse task error: $[?(@.chain=='BTC')] is not a valid array index: keypath not found

path: $[?(@.chain=='BTC')],address

data: $(fetch)
```

I used a comma above to emulate the JSONPath in the chainlink documentation example for [array responses](https://docs.chain.link/any-api/get-request/examples/array-response), But As you will see bellow I have also tried to use a dot operator to access the address value in the object I filter for.

The JSONPath expression is meant to filter and return the BTC address in the array bellow:

```
[
  {
    "address": "bnb1utqrwz3d8p5yfn257ux2s8n90hu6qkgvd8e768",
    "chain": "BNB"
  },
  {
    "address": "0x629e1b35a17cff187349e42aad01a2c7771c29b7",
    "chain": "BSC"
  },
  {
    "address": "bc1qutqrwz3d8p5yfn257ux2s8n90hu6qkgveecely",
    "chain": "BTC"
  }
]
```

I have also tried using dot notion, which throws the below error (Bracket notation also throws an error).

```
parse_address jsonparse
JSONParse task error: $[?(@.chain=='BTC')].address is not a valid array index: keypath not found

path: $[?(@.chain=='BTC')].address

data: $(fetch)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Based on the JSON file you've provided, you'd need to provide the following job config:

```
parse_address [type="jsonparse" path="2,address" data="$(fetch)"]
```

(the address being the key you wish to retrieve within the JSON array element with index #2, as JSON array element indices start at 0)

You can read more about the `jsonparse` tasks type, including an example, here: https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/oracle-jobs/all-tasks#json-parse-task